# Regular expression exclude double character

Tags: regex

I need to have regular expression which find a character which not following by same character after it. Mean exclude double even multiple same character.

For example, when i need to find `'e'` character from string: `"need only single characteeer"`, it is mean will find `'e'` on each words breakdown as below:

`"need"` > not match because it has double `'e'`

`"only"` > not match because no `'e'`

`"single"` > match because has only single `'e'`

`"characteeer"` > not match because has multiple of `'e'`

Not sure whether it is possible or not. Any answer or comment will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Maybe my question above still ambiguous. Actually i need to find the `'e'` character only instead the words. I am going to replace it with double character. So the one which already has double character will not replaced.

The main purpose is to replace `'e'` with `'ee'` for example. But the one which has `'ee'` or `'eee'` already, or even more `'e'`, will be untouched.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

UPDATE:

```
(?<!e)e(?!e)
```

Will match e not with negative lookbehind to prevent preceeding e and negative lookahead preventing following e.

[Can be checked here](https://regex101.com/r/XmnIZv/1)

```
\b(([A-Za-z])(?!\2))+\b
```

Will match a word (sequence of  one or more characters between A-Za-Z), with negative lookahead which prevents following character to be the same as last match, group 2, or using non capturing group.

```
/\b(?:([A-Za-z])(?!\1))+\b/g
```

however `only` will match because it doesn't contain repeated character.
to match [a word containing `e` but no `ee`](https://regex101.com/r/XmnIZv/2)

```
/(?<![a-z])(?=[a-z]*e)(?![a-z]*ee)[a-z]+/gi
```

Answer (score 3):

```
/\b([a-df-z]*e[a-df-z]*)\b\s*/g
```

You could add the flag case insensitive `/i` if needed.

**Explanation:**

```
/               : regex delimiter
  \b            : word boundary
  (             : start group 1
    [a-df-z]*   : 0 or more letter that is not "e"
    e           : 1 letter "e"
    [a-df-z]*   : 0 or more letter that is not "e"
  )             : end group 1
  \b            : word boundary
  \s*           : 0 or more spaces
/g              : regex delimiter, global flag
```

As you didn't give which language you're using, here is a perl script:

```
my $str = "need only single characteeer";
my @list = $str =~  /\b([a-df-z]*e[a-df-z]*)\b\s*/g;
say Dumper\@list;
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = [
          'single'
        ];
```

And a php script:

```
$str = "need only single characteeer";
preg_match_all("/\b([a-df-z]*e[a-df-z]*)\b\s*/", $str, $match);
print_r($match);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => single 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => single
        )

)
```