# Search and replace lines in csv with double quotes using Python

Tags: python, csv, quotes

I need to process some .csv files. Some of them have field entries of 1 double quote (`"`) or possibly several mixed in with other text. I need to escape them all. So far I'm doing this:

```
def process_file():
  input_path = 'input.txt'
  output_path = 'output.txt'
  with open(input_path) as input_file, open(output_path, 'w+') as output_file:
    for line in input_file:
      newline = line.replace('"', '""""')
      output_file.write(newline)
```

How can I make sure that the replace only happens with single characters and does not replace `""` or `""""` for example.

I'd like to use python instead of any command line solution. Also, these files are very large, which is why I'm looping through lines instead of loading the whole thing into memory.

Comment: Have you tried using the `csv` module?

Comment: Can you show an actual example of how the file looks like?

Comment: It's a pipe delimited csv file with millions of rows and 200+ fields

Comment: Haven't used the csv module, looking at it now

Comment: A small representative snippet of a few rows and a few columns would suffice.

Comment: @mkrieger1 edited my question with part of one of the lines with quotes

Comment: I don't see a field that consists of a single `"` in that line. There is a field that *contains* a `"` as part of some larger text. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Ah yes sorry if I worded it funny. I meant that there is only 1 " and not """". There are some fields that contain a single ", but I need to escape all of them

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @mkrieger1 and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47952922/regular-expression-exclude-double-character), I was able to put together this solution:

```
def process_file():
  input_path = 'input.txt'
  output_path = 'output.txt'
  with open(input_path) as input_file, open(output_path, 'w+') as output_file:
    for line in input_file:
      newline = re.sub(r'(?<!")"(?!")', '""""', line)
      output_file.write(newline)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression:

```
import re
newline = re.sub(r'^"$', '"""', line)
```

Comment: That would act on lines which consist *only* of a single quote, but I think that's not the problem here.