# Regex to find string between patterns not containing specific string

Tags: regex

Ok gurus,
Lets say I have the following string:

```
{
"event" : "party" ,
"Id" : "store" ,
"timestamp" : "2019-07-07T13:14:26.329Z" ,
"localDateTime" : "2019-07-07T16:14" ,
"orderStateUpdate" : {
"id" : "fj09bA9ywfGS" ,
"orderId" : "2315043" ,
"visitId" : "2315043" ,
"items" :{{
"id" : "fj09bA6K3K8u" ,
"quantity" : 1 ,
"stat" : "ok"
},
{
"id" : "fj09bA6K3K8u2" ,
"quantity" : 2 ,
"stat" : "ok"
}}
,
"items" :{{
"id" : "fj09bA6K3K8u" ,
"quantity" : 1 ,
"stat" : "junk"
},
{
"id" : "fj09bA6K3K8u2" ,
"quantity" : 2 ,
"stat" : "ok"
}}
,
"extraParams" : {"extraparamstuff1":"bugger"},"somethingelse" :"blahblahblah"
}}
```

The string has two (nested arrays) wrapped by double curly braces. This string specifically contains an error where the LAST curly brace is ALSO double; what I am trying to capture with regex is the string that starts with '}}' , ends with '}}' and DOES NOT CONTAIN '{{' like so:

```
}}
,
"extraParams" : {"extraparamstuff1":"bugger"},"conversationLink" :"https://qa.app.package.ai/qa/#/app/dashboard?d=1561248000000&c=fdxkID9IifGv&p=fdxfaFgV1l1Y"
}}
```

I am Regex-challenged, but have come up with this:

```
(?:(\}\})).*(?:\{\{).*(?:\}\s*?\})
```

which captures

```
}}
,
"items" :{{
"id" : "fj09bA6K3K8u" ,
"quantity" : 1 ,
"itemState" : "LOADED"
},
{
"id" : "fj09bA6K3K8u2" ,
"quantity" : 2 ,
"itemState" : "LOADED2"
}}
,
"extraParams" : {"extraparamstuff1":"bugger"},"conversationLink" :"https://qa.app.package.ai/qa/#/app/dashboard?d=1561248000000&c=fdxkID9IifGv&p=fdxfaFgV1l1Y"
}}
```

which is too much. Can someone help me understand how to find this? This is for error-checking inbound data (and yes I need to check for extra opening '{{' as well).

Comment: Just a thought, but this looks a lot like JSON. Why not try to parse the JSON and then iterate to validate versus using a RegEx on the string? (And yeah, the double curly's are a problem, but maybe you could scan and replace?)

Comment: @jakerella it is indeed json. We are working on a very specific project to "flatten" multidimensional data. We can't use conventional parsing as we have duplicate names in name:value pairs (not all of the code is shown) among other things. We've gotten through everything else except handling this possible scenario (which will be really, really rare... but possible).

Comment: Ugh, gotcha... well, I think you can do this. I'll tinker a bit if no one comes up with an answer before me.

Comment: Do you always know that this bit you want to capture is at the _end_ of the test string? Could it be in the middle with other properties after it?

Comment: @jakerella no that is the problem-we will not know the position. 99% of the time IF it happens it SHOULD be at the end of the string (we can easily rtrim it or something once we know)... If we can find the pattern where closing (or opening; gotta do both) double braces repeat with no opening (or closing;reverse) braces in the containing string then we found the offending pair and can remove them.

Comment: So, I think you're going to need a [negative lookbehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47952922/regular-expression-exclude-double-character) then, and I'm trying to work that up, but those aren't easy. Also, not supported in the ECMAScript Regex engine... are you doing this in JavaScript, oooor...?

Comment: Actually, you WANT the double... so maybe it will work in JS with a positive lookahead... still testing.

Comment: ooor...:-) This will actually be in a PHP page, data loaded into a database after flattening. FWIW the "json" is being handled strictly as a string; a big, looong string...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so, I think you need a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) since you have to accept curly braces, but not doubles... this is what I've come up with, not sure if it will work in every case though.

`}}([^{]|{(?!{))+}}`

It basically says: look for two closing curlies (`}}`), then either any non-opening curly character (`[^{]`) OR a single opening curly character (using negative lookahead) (`{(?!{)`), repeat that as many times as needed (`+`), and finish with a double closing curly (`}}`)

Link to live (updateable) demo: https://regex101.com/r/kwlzco/2